# Plotting streams of vector fields

Tags: pgfplots, wolfram-mathematica

So I have the vector field `${x^2+2*x*y,y^2+2*x*y}` and I would like to plot 'streams.' `quiver` from `pgfplots` does produce arrows (which I normalise) but I think that streams would make things easier to understand. Here is a `StreamPlot` that mathematica creates.

[image: Plot of vector field in mathematica]

[image]

I would like to be able to make something like this with `pgfplots` to be able to maintain style consistency. Perhaps if I could extract the points that produce the curves then that could be plotted with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think quiver plots in PGFPlots always produce *straight* arrows in in the above image the arrows aren't all straight. But I think your last suggestion should work, i.e. storing the points of the curves in a file that than is used by PGFPlots. I think you will "program" a solution to store the points in the file, so as a hint: You have to introduce empty lines so that the PGFPlots "jumps" to the start of the new curve instead of "drawing" to the start point of a new curve.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the answer. I was merely throwing out possibilities but I do not know how to extract points, either from Mathematica or elsewhere, if you could advise on that issue.

Comment: I never used Mathematica, but googling found e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html or https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html. Hopefully that helps. Good luck!

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks. I managed to get the extracted points and they are in a text file but I'm not sure how to plot them smoothly from the text file, if you know the answer to that. (I haven't used pgfplots before).

Comment: @StefanPinnow ok I found out how to plot them smoothly, but is there an efficient way to plot all 107 files? They are called 'line1.txt', 'line2.txt', so some sort of loop with pattern matching?

Comment: @StefanPinnow never mind I found out how

Comment: @user110503: That does look great! Would you mind writing an answer to your own question? This could be really useful to a lot of people.

Comment: @Jake sure I can do that, but I will say the solution is very 'problem specific' in that I used facts only true to this problem. It is probably generalisable. As long as someone understands what the idea is I think they could adapt it however.

Comment: @user110503: Yeah, I think even if the solution isn't general, it'll help someone with a similar problem to at least have a starting point.

Comment: Take a look at [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).  The documentation (in the latest version) even has a section on style consistency.

Answer (score 5):

I used this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file initially. The first element in the plot `dynamicalStream` was an empty string plus an object [`GraphicsComplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html). I extracted the points from the plot with `points = dynamicalStream[[1]][[2]][[1]]`. It may be different for someone else. The `Line` objects from this `GraphicsComplex` object were extracted with (and I apologise for the way I did this, there are probably better methods)

```
lines = dynamicalStream[[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[2 ;; Length[ dynamicalStream[[1]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]]]] ].
```

I'd say this is unlikely to be useful, so either you find a more general method or do what I did which is manually find the correct part of the list to extract from.

I then created a list where each element is itself a list of points for each line. This was done with `pointstable = 
 Table[points[[#[[1]][[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[#[[1]]]}] & /@ lines`. The inner list was created by going through each element in the `Line` object (this is a position of a point in the `points` list) and extracting the correct point. Thus you make a list of points corresponding to the `Line`. This is then mapped over each `Line` object in `lines` so the final list is of the described form.

I then saved each list in a separate text file: 
`Export["line" <> IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #,"Table"] &~MapIndexed~pointstable`
 as described in the link.

I plotted with:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
  \tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
            \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,...,107}{
                \addplot[black,->-=0.5] table[]{line\i.txt};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

After looking at that link properly, an easier way to do it would be:

```
points  = Cases[dynamicalStream, GraphicsComplex[data__] :> data, -3, 1][[1]]
lines = Cases[dynamicalStream, Line[data__] :> data, -3];
pointstable = Table[points[[#[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[#]}] & /@ lines
```

Comment: That looks good. Even better it would be, if you could also add the output of PGFPlots to your answer, because we don't have your TXT files. (And just for your information: Maybe you have seen that I have edited your answer already. Instead of always writing `<code>foo\</code>` you can use the shortcut `\`foo\``.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Sorry I'm not exactly sure what want me to add.

Comment: You should move the resulting image of LaTeX/PGFPlots to *the answer* instead of *the question* ;)