# pgfplots or tikz curved axis/surface for vector field

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-3dplot

I am looking to draw a 2D plane of vectors in latex. Essentially a combination of the following two pictures.
I can do the first picture with just `\path` and `\draw`, and the second with `quiver`. But, I cant seem to be able to do both. How would I go about doing this?

**Image 1**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[black,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt] 
  (0,0) to[out=-10,in=150] (6,-2) -- (12,1) to[out=150,in=-10] (5.5,3.7) -- cycle;
  (0,0) to[out=-10,in=150] (6,-2) -- (12,1) to[out=150,in=-10] (5.5,3.7) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Image 2**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
    ymin = -4, ymax = 4,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
    axis equal image,
    xtick distance = 1,
    ytick distance = 1,
    view = {20}{90},
    scale = 1.25,
]
 
\addplot3[
    quiver = {
        u = {sin y},
        v = {sin x},
        scale arrows = 0.05,
    },
    quiver/colored = {blue},
    -stealth,
    domain = -4:4,
    domain y = -4:4,
] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by doing "both"? Should they be in the same picture, i.e. overlapping?

Comment: @Gargantuar, i'm not sure how else to describe... The 2nd picture (the vector field) should be on the surface. Not necessary that specific vector field. So the outcome is a curved surface with its corresponding vector field. Something _like_ [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/SliceVectorPlot3D.en/O_2.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, what does your current code look like, could you edit it into your question please?

Comment: @jamesT Hello! Thank you. I have added the code

Comment: A possible solution would be to draw an explicit vector field on the surface.  Maybe this answer gives you some hints. [stream plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685528/stream-plot-in-tikz-with-singularities/687227#687227)