Drawing graph for all curves describing solutions to differential equations
I apologise at the outset for not publishing any code, mainly because I have no idea how to do this.
Although I have managed to produce the graphs by hand and have a reference figure, I have yet to find any examples where curves describing the solutions of differential equations can be represented in TikZ and/or PGFPlots. What I am looking for is a kind of iterative method that can be applied to different equations without the need to write down every equation (unless you necessarily have to code every equation).
The reference example is
$$y' = x^2 - y^2$$,
and the reference figure is as follows (Credit: https://people.dm.unipi.it/acquistp/analisi1.pdf).

Edit: I actually found this answer on slope/vector field for all solutions of the differential equation, but I did not understand the implementation of the numerical solution and representation on PGFPlots.
I would like to point out that this question does not so much seek a solution to the specific equation presented: the aim is in fact to obtain, by means of a reference example such as this (it could also have been another), a generic method for a similar representation to the reference graph.
Can you provide answers on this?

Welcome! Questions which just post a picture and ask other people to provide code for it aren't really reasonable questions on this site. (Somewhere else, you could maybe hire somebody for this, but that's not here.) What have you tried? If you've no idea at all, why tag it tikz-pgf and pgfplots? Can you code one of the curves? Note that your question shouldn't depend on an external link. Alternatively, have you considered doing this in another application and just using \includegraphics?

@cfr I've edited the original question, pointing out that I'm not asking to provide code for a picture, but to explain, through an example like the one I presented, a generic solution. (I don't want to use \includegraphics to insert images from external applications: images are usually grainy).

"images are usually grainy" The quality of an image largely depends on the format. If you want to avoid grainy images, choose a vector format instead.

@Bml not really clear what you are asking. In general the pgfplots manual (and this site) have hundreds of example plots, what is different about this one that you are asking about, why can't this simply be closed as a duplicate of any question about pgfplots if you are just asking "in general". Or if you find it simpler, plot the graph in something else such as mathematica or whatever and include it with \includegraphcs.

@DavidCarlisle I have not found, on this site, examples that reproduce a graph with all the solutions of differential equations drawn as in the graph I have given. If I have not been particularly meticulous in my search, could you link some examples that reproduce, in general, graphs like the one I included in the original question?

@Bml take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685528/stream-plot-in-tikz-with-singularities/687227#687227.  You will find in my answer the code for the Runge-Kutta method and obtain the curves you are looking for.
